# Php switch statement - how to manage repeated cases?

Tags: php, switch-statement

I'm building a site in which the user should be able to select from three regions where the content should be visible. I have the following regions:

- Region 1: Argentina, Uruguay, Paraguay, Chile, Venezuela, Peru
- Region 2: Mexico, Colombia, Ecuador, Brazil, Belize, Costa Rica, El 
  Salvador, Guatemala, Honduras, Nicaragua, Panama
- Region 0: It should include all of the countries above

I have the following switch statement:

```
switch ( $countryCode ) {
    case 'AR':
    case 'UY':
    case 'PY':
    case 'CL':
    case 'VE':
    case 'PR':
        // code to execute
        break;

    case 'MX':
    case 'CO':
    case 'EC':
    case 'BR':
    case 'BZ':
    case 'CR':
    case 'SV':
    case 'GT':
    case 'HN':
    case 'NI':
    case 'PA':
        // code to execute
        break;

    case 'AR':
    case 'UY':
    case 'PY':
    case 'CL':
    case 'VE':
    case 'PR':
    case 'MX':
    case 'CO':
    case 'EC':
    case 'BR':
    case 'BZ':
    case 'CR':
    case 'SV':
    case 'GT':
    case 'HN':
    case 'NI':
    case 'PA':
        // code to execute
        break;

    default:
        // code to execute
        break;
}
```

I'm having trouble with the structure of my switch code, in the part where I have to include all of the countries (Region 0). It seems that I can't repeat countries that have been declared on previous case statements (it's obvious I know), but I can't figure out the right way to do it.

Is there any way to restructure my code so there would be a case statement that includes all of the countries? If it's not posible to do it with a switch, you guys have any other suggestion?

Thank you!

Comment: You should be switching on the region code, not on the individual countries. *Pick your region. Your choices are 1) list of countries, 2) list of other countries, or 0) all countries. Your choice:*, then `switch ($region) case 1:...break; case 2: ... break;` etc.

Comment: Well the regions are being defined by my client (not standard regionalization), they separated the countries that way and want to be able to show content to all the countries by selecting "Region 0".

Any suggestion? :(

Comment: I think I get what you're trying to say now! Thanks, will give it a try!

Comment: @LuisCarlosPando Given client may want to change selection of countries, it is best not to hard-code the regions in the switch loop, I will update the function to use external source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @KenWhite mentioned, group by region, then check against regions.

Your code could look something like this:

```
<?php

$regions = [false, false, false];

switch ( $countryCode ) {
    case 'AR':
    case 'UY':
    case 'PY':
    case 'CL':
    case 'VE':
    case 'PR':
        $regions[0] = $regions[1] = true;
        break;

    case 'MX':
    case 'CO':
    case 'EC':
    case 'BR':
    case 'BZ':
    case 'CR':
    case 'SV':
    case 'GT':
    case 'HN':
    case 'NI':
    case 'PA':
        $regions[0] = $regions[2] = true;
        break;

    default:
        break;
}

if($regions[0]) {
    //some code here
}
// etc.
```

Comment: I think this is the way to go, but can you explain me how can you group by region with `$regions = [false, false, false];` and `$regions[0] = $regions[1] = true;` and `$regions[0] = $regions[2] = true;`

I'm having a hard time trying to understand that logic.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @LuisCarlosPando, the line `$regions = [false, false, false]` is defaulting the `$regions` array values to `false` by default (we don't yet know where each country belongs, so, by default, each region is `false`). In the `switch case` section, we then set the appropriate regions to `true` according to each country's abbreviated form. So, for example, `'AR'`: This country (according to the mapping you provided in your question) belongs to both *region 1* and *region 0*. In the `switch case` we set `$regions[0]` and `$regions[1]` to `true` (`$regions` `0th` and `1st` elements)

Comment: Thanks @ctwheels! 

So down below you do the checking of which of the regions returns `true` with the if statements, right?

I already did that and it seems to work! But I would like to finally ask you the way you would formulate the validations?

I did something like this:

`if ($regions[0]) { // do something }` then `if ($regions[1]) { // do something }` and finally `if ($regions[2]) { // do something }`

Please notice I'm not using `elseif`. Is that the way it should be done? Thank you for your help @ctwheels!

Comment: @LuisCarlosPando Assuming you want to run multiple code blocks and that countries can be in any region or multiple regions, multiple if statements would probably be the way to go. The only part that you could potentially use `elseif` would be when comparing the *sub-regional* sections. So for example `if($regions[0]) { //do something } if($regions[1]) { //do something } elseif ($regions[2]) { //do something }`. Not sure if this makes any sense to you?

Comment: Got it now, thanks so much for your advice @ctwheels!

Answer (score 0):

Options A) hard code your scenario (bad idea)

```
function get_region($country_code){

    switch ( $country_code ) {
        case 'AR':
        case 'UY':
        case 'PY':
        case 'CL':
        case 'VE':
        case 'PR':
            return 1;
            break;

        case 'MX':
        case 'CO':
        case 'EC':
        case 'BR':
        case 'BZ':
        case 'CR':
        case 'SV':
        case 'GT':
        case 'HN':
        case 'NI':
        case 'PA':
            return 2;
            break;

        default:
            return 0;
            break;
    }
}

echo get_region("AR")."\n";
echo get_region("MX")."\n";
```

Option B) use external .ini files

regions.ini

```
; region 1
[1]
country[] = "AR"
country[] = "UY"
country[] = "PY"
country[] = "CL"
country[] = "VE"
country[] = "PE"

; region 2
[2]
country[] = "MX"
country[] = "CO"
country[] = "EC"
country[] = "BR"
country[] = "BZ"
country[] = "CR"
country[] = "SV"
country[] = "GT"
country[] = "HN"
country[] = "NI"
country[] = "PA"
```

function.php:

```
function get_region($country_code){

    $region = parse_ini_file("regions.ini", true);

    if (in_array($country_code,$region[1]['country'], false)){
        return 1;
    } elseif (in_array($country_code,$region[2]['country'], false)){
        return 2;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

echo get_region("AR")."\n";
echo get_region("MX")."\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, you have two mutually exclusive code paths and one inclusive one. I would move away from using `switch` and use sets (i.e. PHP arrays).

```
$region1 = array_combine(['AR','UY','PY','CL','VE','PR'],true);
$region2 = array_combine(['MX','CO','EC','BR','BZ','CR','SV',
                          'GT','HN','NI','PA',],true);

if (isset($region1[$countryCode])) {
    // Region 1 specific...

}
else if (isset($region2[$countryCode])) {
    // Region 2 specific...

}

if (isset($region1[$countryCode],$region2[$countryCode])) {
    // Region 0 specific...

}
else {
    // Default case...

}
```

Better yet (if possible) move the code paths to their own functions:

```
function region1() { }
function region2() { }
function region0() { }

$region1 = array_combine(['AR','UY','PY','CL','VE','PR'],true);
$region2 = array_combine(['MX','CO','EC','BR','BZ','CR','SV',
                          'GT','HN','NI','PA',],true);

if (isset($region1[$countryCode])) {
    region1();
    region0();
}
else if (isset($region2[$countryCode])) {
    region2();
    region0();
}
else {
    // Default case...

}
```